# name of event when mouse is pressed without releasing?

Tags: jquery, events

I want to know the name of the mouse event when It is keep pressing without releasing it.I know about mousedown, mouseclick.

I want to perform different - different action on both the events.One action on mouseclick and another when mouse is pressed withour releasing.

Comment: Why not using mousedown? If you are looking for just styling, there is also CSS pseudo class ':active'. Or please elaborate on what you are looking for...

Comment: Almost the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163642/javascript-long-click-for-a-bookmarklet It is not an event though...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [JavaScript while mousedown](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15505272/1456376)

Comment: I want to perform some actions inside these two events and mousedown is not the solution.I want action when mouse is pressed and not released

Comment: Mousedown is not a solution for what? We still don't know what you are looking for???

Answer (score 1):

If you need an event to trigger after holding an element for some time you could use the .mousedown event and then use setTimeout to run the function with a delay. You should bind a clear timer function to the mouseup event.

Answer (score 0):

It still sounds like you're looking for `.mousedown()`

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

To clarify: If you want some code to execute repeatedly until the mouse is released (I can't quite tell if that's actually what you want), you could use something like this:

```
var interval = -1;

function doThing(){
    console.log("this will execute 10 times per second while the mouse is held down");
}

$('#element').mousedown(function(){
    if(interval !== -1)
        clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(doThing, 100);
});

$('#element').mouseup(function(){
    if(interval !== -1)
        clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: As he says: `I know about mousedown, mouseclick.`

Comment: I see that. It still sounds like what he's asking for is mousedown(). "Pressed without releasing" is the mouse down event.

Comment: The phrase "long press" was never used. That would have helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for `MouseHold event` .

Here is a [light weight plugin](http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/) for that.

Here you can use the open [source code](http://remysharp.com/demo/mousehold.js) to  get the things done.

Comment: how will i use this mousehold.

Comment: Copy the code into your js file and add like mouse down event.

Comment: I copied it but it is working for mouse click also while I dont need this on mouse click instead mouse clicked for a long time. Thanks